# Kubernetes Pods Always ContainerCreating

Tags: kubernetes, centos7, kubectl, kubeadm

I have installed a cluster of one master and one node using kubadm

`kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.0", GitCommit:"fc32d2f3698e36b93322a3465f63a14e9f0eaead", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-03-26T16:44:10Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}`

Whenever I try and install a pod (ngix, gafana, influxdb, heapster, tiller), it always stays in a state of ContainerCreating.

I can't figure out how to diagnose the issue to try and get the containers to move to a Running state.

Comment: Generally speaking, you will want to check the logs of the kubelet responsible for your pod and ideally logs from any containers created by the pod. Kubelet may tell you it can't launch the container for whatever reason, and if it does at least get to the point of launching, the container logs will be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following commands to check logs of Kubelet and diagnose the issue accordingly:

```
systemctl status kubelet
journalctl -xeu kubelet
```

For details:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-cluster/